# Start an approval assigned to people field (multi-selection) fails

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, flow, power-automate, approval-process

I have an  approval workflow "when a new item is created" that works fine if the manager field (assigned to) is a people field with no option to select more approvers.

If I change it to "allow multiple selection" then the flow fails.

It creates me an apply to each section that I do not need here.

How can I put the assigned to field on the start an approval section to an array or something that accept multiple email addresses?

Answer (score 0):

To specify multiple users, use a semi-colon (`;`) to separate user identifies.

The `AssignedTo` field can accept user identities in the form of:

- Email address (not just the primary)
- User Principal Name (UPN)
- AAD user id (in the format XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX)

**Documentation**: [Approvals - Approval recipient format](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/approvals/)

Comment: Hi @kurt, did you try my suggestions? Please [Upvote(^)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) and [accept as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if it helped you. I will also help other users to find the answers in future.

Answer (score 0):

**Please following steps:**

1.Add "**When an item is created**" trigger

2.Add "**Initialize variable**" action

- Name: AssignedToPeople
- Type:String

3.Add "**Append to string variable**" action

- Name:AssignedToPeople
- Value:AssignTo Email**;**

4.Add "**Start and wait for an approval**" action:

- Approval type:Approve/Reject - Everyone must approve
- Title: Send Approvel Email
- Assigned to: AssignedToPeople (from Variables)

[image]

5.Save and Test this flow

[image]